# How to populate previsouly selected value as default value using react-select in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Hi i am new to Reactjs i am working with react-select component i want to populate react-select dropdown with pre-selected value as an defaultValue of the react-select i am fetching data through api it returns json object array but no luck.
Anybody please help..

Below is my code which i have tried but unable to populate my react-select dropdown.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Form, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Select from 'react-select';
import makeAnimated from 'react-select/animated';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const BaseapiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();

class Editmcq extends Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mcqname: '',
            qnaoptionlist: [],
            qnaoptionlistarr: [],
            preSelectedOpt: [],
            qna: '',
            status: '',
            isDeleted: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.drpdwnhandleChange = this.drpdwnhandleChange.bind(this);
    }

componentDidMount(props) {
        var Mcqid = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.getMcqById(Mcqid);
    }
    getMcqById(Mcqid) {
        const apiUrl = BaseapiUrl + "/api/v1/web/mcq/" + Mcqid;
        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    debugger;
                    if (result) {
                        console.warn(result.data);
                        this.setState({
                            mcqname: result.data.name,
                            qnaoptionlistarr: result.data.qna
                        });
                        const options = this.state.qnaoptionlistarr.map(d => ({
                            "value": d._id,
                            "label": d.question
                        }));
                        for (var i of options) {
                            this.state.preSelectedOpt.push(i);
                        }
                        console.log(this.state.preSelectedOpt);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("record not found!")
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({ IsApiError: true });
                }
            )
    }
render() {
        debugger;
        var myopt = this.state.preSelectedOpt;
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group controlId="mcqname">
                                <Form.Label>Mcq Name</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    name="mcqname"
                                    value={this.state.mcqname}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    placeholder="Mcq Name" />
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group controlId="qnaoptionlist">
                                <Select
                                    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                                    components={animatedComponents}
                                    defaultValue={myopt}
                                    onChange={this.drpdwnhandleChange}
                                    isMulti
                                    options={myopt}
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Button variant="success" onClick={() => this.updateMcq()}>Update</Button>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
export default Editmcq;
```

want to achieve similar to like this

[image: output]